# using createBitmap method to encode QR As Bitmap makes padding

Tags: android, bitmap, qr-code

I want to display bitmap to an ImageView with no padding but I think createBitmap method adds padding. here's the code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="15mm"
        android:layout_height="15mm"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_gravity="center"  />


result = new QRCodeWriter().encode(str, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, width, null);
            int w = result.getWidth();
            int h = result.getHeight();
            int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                int offset = y * w;
                for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                    pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
                }
            }


      Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
```

bitmap wont fit to imageview.

Answer (score 0):

please using scaleType="fitXY"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="15mm"
            android:layout_height="15mm"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="center"  />
```

Generate QrCode : https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.4.0'
    }
```

Example code : `Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(mCustomer_data.getCustomer_code()).bitmap();`

Comment: I added  scaleType="fitXY" but it doesn't work . I use this code to generate QrCode: I edited my post.

Comment: i have putted qr code generator dependency so try this method and check. ex : 'Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(mCustomer_data.getCustomer_code()).bitmap();'